# Как сгруппировать колонку с датой по дням?

Tags: python, дата, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня есть датасет с колонкой в формате даты:

```
868 2018-11-23 11:00:12.125231
35  2018-11-23 12:27:24.238886
590 2018-11-16 13:21:11.921000
791 2018-11-18 16:24:22.116547
415 2018-11-26 02:52:18.005350
```

Как можно сделать разбивку по дням, чтобы построить диаграмму с количеством операций, совершенных в этот день?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [pd.Grouper()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html).

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date_column_name", freq="D"))...
```

---

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame({'val':np.random.randint(100, size=20), 'date':pd.date_range('2018-12-01', freq='500T', periods=20)})

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
    val                date
0    65 2018-12-01 00:00:00
1    63 2018-12-01 08:20:00
2     8 2018-12-01 16:40:00
3    12 2018-12-02 01:00:00
4     0 2018-12-02 09:20:00
5    74 2018-12-02 17:40:00
6    86 2018-12-03 02:00:00
7    27 2018-12-03 10:20:00
8    57 2018-12-03 18:40:00
9     7 2018-12-04 03:00:00
10    7 2018-12-04 11:20:00
11   19 2018-12-04 19:40:00
12    3 2018-12-05 04:00:00
13   68 2018-12-05 12:20:00
14   29 2018-12-05 20:40:00
15   11 2018-12-06 05:00:00
16   68 2018-12-06 13:20:00
17   25 2018-12-06 21:40:00
18    6 2018-12-07 06:00:00
19   23 2018-12-07 14:20:00
```

группировка:

```
In [17]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="D")).agg({'val':['sum','min','max','mean']})
Out[17]:
            val
            sum min max       mean
date
2018-12-01  136   8  65  45.333333
2018-12-02   86   0  74  28.666667
2018-12-03  170  27  86  56.666667
2018-12-04   33   7  19  11.000000
2018-12-05  100   3  68  33.333333
2018-12-06  104  11  68  34.666667
2018-12-07   29   6  23  14.500000

In [18]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="D")).sum()
Out[18]:
            val
date
2018-12-01  136
2018-12-02   86
2018-12-03  170
2018-12-04   33
2018-12-05  100
2018-12-06  104
2018-12-07   29
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [[1, '08-11-17 10:58:11'], [2, '09-11-18 10:58:11'], [3, '09-11-18 11:58:11'], [4, '10-12-18 10:58:11']]

dt = {}
for (count, date_time) in data:
    (date, time) = date_time.split(' ', 1)
    (day_month, year) = date.rsplit('-', 1)
    dt.setdefault(year, {}).setdefault(day_month, 0)
    dt[year][day_month] += count

import json
print(json.dumps(dt, indent=2))
```

`{
  "17": {
    "08-11": 1
  },
  "18": {
    "09-11": 5,
    "10-12": 4
  }
}`

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('08-11-17 10:58:11', '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')
print(d.year, d.month, d.day)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно сделать разбивку по дням, чтобы построить диаграмму с количеством операций, совершенных в этот день?

```
**df_D** - новый df сгруппированный согласно условия (сумма по дням);
**df** - исходный df;
**D** - признак 'по дням', аналогично можно по M,Y;
**date** - колонка df с датами.

df_D=df.resample('D', on ='date').sum().reset_index()
df_D.plot(x='date', y='val', title = 'Количество операций по дням')
```